# Return request Extended not working in Django

Tags: html, django

I newbie in Django and I'm confused on how can I hide some tags in my extends html, let say I have `dashboard.html` and it is being extends to the `index.html` which contains side bar etc. and I want to hide some of my side bar based on the roles and permissions of the user, let say if user is admin the side bar can be view, but the problem it is not being accessible to `index.html` since it is just an extend to dashboard.

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("dashboard")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request, user)
            request.session['user_id'] = user.id
            request.session['username'] = user.username
            request.session['fullname'] = user.first_name + user.last_name
            return redirect("dashboard")
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid Username and Password.')

    return render(request, 'login.html')


@login_required(login_url='login')
def dashboard(request):
    user_details = get_user_details(request)
    allowed_roles = ["Admin", "Management"]
    role = RoleDetails.objects.filter(id=user_details.role_id).first()

    context = {
        'user_role' : role.role_name,
        'role_permission': role.role_name,
    }

    return render(request, 'dashboard.html',context)
```

**dashboard.html**

```
{% extends 'index.html' %} {% block content %} {% load staticfiles %}
<div> ............... etc.
```

**index.html** contains sidebar etc. let say I want to hide it if it is not equals to admin, I tried putting `role_permission` in admin it should in `index.html` but it is being extended? Is there anyway to modify? did I missed something?

```
 {% if role_permission =='Admin' %}
     <li class="menu-item {% if url_name == 'inventory-in' %}active{% endif %}">
       <a href="{% url 'inventory-in' %}" class="menu-link">
          <i class="menu-icon tf-icons ti ti-stack-push"></i>
             <div data-i18n="In">In</div>
       </a>
     </li>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: what's showing in browser when you add {{ role_permission }} ?

Comment: try or `RoleDetails.objects.get(id=user_details.role_id).first()`